# How would I raise integers in a list to successive powers? (python)

Tags: python, list, loops, exponent

Beginner here.

I want to raise elements(integers) in the list to the power of x+1, but am stuck.

For example:

- Lst = [a, b, c, d, e]
- a^x, b^(x+1), c^(new x + 1), d^(new x + 1), and so forth..

Another example:

- Lst = [8, 7, 8, 5, 7]
- x = 2

[8^2, 7^3, 8^4, 5^5, 7^6] is the output I would like..

Thank you!!!

I tried various for-loops to iterate into the elements of the list; pow(iterable, x+1). I've been at it for a few days but can't figure it out. I am also new to programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [8, 7, 8, 5, 7]
x = 2

out = [v ** i for i, v in enumerate(lst, x)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[64, 343, 4096, 3125, 117649]
```

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) can help you increment `x` here:

```py
from itertools import count

lst = [8, 7, 8, 5, 7]
x = count(2)

print([ele ** next(x) for ele in lst])
```

Output

```
[64, 343, 4096, 3125, 117649]
```